# Checking existence of a function in a library in linux

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

During dynamic linking a weird undefined function reference appears. I know the name of the library which should contain this function. Is there any Linux command to make sure the function exists in the library (.a file)?

Comment: Try `nm <your_lib>`, if your symbol prefixed with `t` or `T` the lib has it.

Comment: [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) does this when checking for library availability with the [`AC_CHECK_LIB`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Libraries) function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use `nm` (might require the `--demangle` parameter) to get a list of everything being inside the library, then use `grep` to filter the results, e.g. look for `\d T functionname\(` or something like that.

Comment: The library has the function name prefixed with T. But the function name is not exactly what I expect. nm finds:
`0000000000000310 T _Z15lmp_init_deviceiiiiidii` 
while I am looking for lmp_init_device.
Would be prefix/suffix ignored during linking?

Comment: Add `--demangle` and it should remove the added characters (caused due to it being C++ rather than plain C).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to `nm` command which should give you the piece of information you are looking for